# Is LSMinimumSystemVersion all that's required to enforce minimum Mac OS system requirement?

Tags: macos, cocoa

My OS X app (soon to be released outside the App Store) requires 10.9 and above. I have `LSMinimumSystemVersion` set to 10.9. Is that all that needs to be done, or do I need to write some code to check the OS version and show an error message?

I'm asking because this line from [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-113253) (emphasis mine) gives me pause:

> If the minimum system version is not available, OS X **tries to** display
>   an alert panel notifying the user of that fact.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the LSMinimumSystemVersion plist key first appeared in a much older version of OS X (10.2?), so it will probably work everywhere you need it to.